# Google fusion query Unable to use aggregate functions - "Could not parse query"

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Am trying out google fusion table queries …. 
I can’t seem to use aggregate functions or Upper() etc…  it works fine without them.

error: "Could not parse query".

http://jsfiddle.net/leebasky/j7kok7yz/

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
 var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
 var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?&tq=', opts);

query.setQuery('SELECT col0 as test, upper(col2) from 1198pzojwSFwuyeL8hsrmKYVHNLdNsB44bxecZYs0  limit 10');


query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +             response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  var data = response.getDataTable();

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
}
```

Comment: COUNT, SUM, AVERAGE, MAXIMUM & MINIMUM are supported, nothing else. https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference

Comment: Thanks.
Is there a way round to aggregate using the APIs date functions like YEAR( ).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the desired functions are currently not available.

But when you only want to apply a different format for the data this may be achieved.

The uppercase may be done via CSS `text-transform: uppercase`.

The YEAR you may get via a [date-formatter](http://google.visualization.DateFormat) :`{pattern: 'yyyy'}`

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
    var opts = {
        sendMethod: 'auto'
    };
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?&tq=', opts);

    query.setQuery('SELECT col0 as test, col2 from 1198pzojwSFwuyeL8hsrmKYVHNLdNsB44bxecZYs0  limit 10');


    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
        pattern: 'yyyy'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 0);


    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, {
        showRowNumber: true
    });
}
```

```css
#table_div tbody tr td:nth-child(3){
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['table']}]}"></script>
       <div id="table_div"></div>
```